# C# Console application: Console.Readkey() has odd initial skipping behaviour on high framerates

Tags: c#, input, timer, keyboard, console-application

For the challenge and educational gain, i am currently trying to make a simple game *in the console window*. I use a very primitive "locked" framerate system as such:

```
 using System.Threading;

    // ... 

    static private void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Timer timer = new Timer(Update);
        timer.Change(0, GameSpeed);

        autoEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

So, a timer ticks every `GameSpeed` miliseconds, and calls the method `Update()`.

The way that i have understood input in the console window so far is as follows:
The console application has a "queue" where it stores any keyboard input as metadata + an instance of a `ConsoleKey` enum. The user can add to this queue *at any time*. If the user holds down, say A, it will add A every computer frame. That is, the actual fastest amount the computer can do, *not* the locked frames i am working with.

Calling `Console.Readkey()` will remove and return the first element on this list. `Console.KeyAvailable` returns a bool indicating whether the list is empty.

If `GameSpeed`is set to anything higher than 400 everything consistently works fine. The below image displays the results of some `Console.WriteLine()` debug messages that give the amount of keyboard inputs detected in this locked/custom frame, using the following code:

```
int counter = 0;
            while (Console.KeyAvailable) { counter++; Console.ReadKey(true); }
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn8JH.png)

I use only the A key. I hold it for some time, then release it again. The `GameSpeed` is set to 1000. As expected, the first frames give low numbers as i might start pressing half into the frame, and so too with the last frames, as i might release the A early.

[Now, the exact same experiment but with a GameSpeed of only 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnvYF.png)

As you can see, i've marked the places i begun pressing with yellow. It always, perfectly gets the first frame. But then theres either one, two, or three frames where it acts as if it has gotten *no inputs*, but then after those frames it's fine and gets around 7 inputs pr frame.

I recognize that you are not supposed to make games in the console window. It is not made for scenarios like this. That does not however eliminate the possibility that there is some specific, logical reason this happens, that i might be able to fix. So, concretely the question is: **can anyone provide some knowledge / ideas of why this happens?**

If computer specs are needed, just say so in the comments and i'll add them.

**Edit**:
I think i have found the cause of this error, and it is windows keyboard *repeat delay*. While you can change this in the control panel, i have searched the web and found no examples of how you would change it in a c# application. The question then boils down to: **how do you change windows keyboard repeat delay**?